# How to put a character at a specific point in a character array?

Tags: c

I am making a simple tic tac toe game. I've run into problems storing the user's choice.
I basically have a struct called userBoard that has a character array of size 12. The user will be presented with a board with each location numbered. The user then has to pick a location to put their character in. The user's character (X or O) will be allotted to them randomly. When the user types in a number, it is passed to a function called updateUserBoard. updateUserBoard will then put the user's character to whatever location the user chose. The problem I have now is that instead of putting the users character only at one location of the array, it fills the whole array with the users character. The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printBoard(void);
void updateUserBoard(int location, char userCharacter, char computerCharacter);

struct UserTicTacToeBoard {
    char user[12]; // A user character array to store the users character.
};

struct ComputerTicTacToeBoard {
    char comp[12];
};

typedef struct UserTicTacToeBoard UserTicTacToeBoard;
typedef struct ComputerTicTacToeBoard ComputerTicTacToeBoard;

UserTicTacToeBoard userBoard;
ComputerTicTacToeBoard compBoard;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Welcome to a game of tic tac toe.\n");
    printf("Let's see if you're smarter than the computer.\n");
    char computerCharacter, userCharacter;
    /* Getting a random number needs some fixing! */
    int assignRandom = (rand() % 10000) / 10000.0;
    int userDecision;
    switch(assignRandom) {
        case 1:
        strcpy(&userCharacter, "O");
        strcpy(&computerCharacter, "X");
        break;

        default:
        strcpy(&userCharacter, "X");
        strcpy(&computerCharacter, "O");
        break;
    }

    printf("Computer gets %c\n", computerCharacter);
    printf("User gets %c\n", userCharacter);
    printBoard();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        userBoard.user[i] = computerCharacter;
        compBoard.comp[i] = userCharacter;
    }

    while(1) {
    printf("\nLadies first.\n");
    printf("Please enter a number from the table above which you would like to replace with\nNumber: ");
    // Use some other function here instead of scanf. If the user types anything other than an int,
    // scanf goes into this crazy loop.
    scanf("%d", &userDecision);
    updateUserBoard(userDecision, userCharacter, computerCharacter);
    }
    return 0;
}

void printBoard(void)
{
    printf(" 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |\n");
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf(" 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |\n");
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf(" 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |\n");
}

void updateUserBoard(int location, char userCharacter, char computerCharacter)
{
    if (location > 11) {
        printf("ERROR: PUSSY DETECTED. GROW A PAIR.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    userBoard.user[location] = userCharacter; // Here instead of putting the user's character to userBoard.user[location], it fills the whole array with the users location 

    printf(" %c  | %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location]);
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf(" %c  | %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location]);
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf(" %c  | %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location]);
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf(" %c  | %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location], userBoard.user[location]);
}
```

Comment: wrong `strcpy(&userCharacter, "O");` , simply `userCharacter = 'O';`

Comment: so `strcpy` only for strings. so for characters i can just assign them a value the normal way. am i right?

Comment: case `strcpy(&userCharacter, "O");`,  this code will destroy the memory of the unexpected.

Comment: don't really understand you... why would it destroy the memory of the unexpected?

Comment: "O" is {'O', '\0'} 2 char need. but userCharacter is one char area. strcpy do copy include '\0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ending of the updateUserBoard function to something like this:

Some notes

- For-loop makes the code shorter. Its contents are run 12 (=board width * board height) times
- The "if" block in the loop is executed when all the cells in one line have been drawn (iterator `i` is greater than zero and its and row width's modulus are zero (i.e. it's time to draw the next line)). This is where the row changes.

The code itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    printf("%c  |", userBoard.user[i]);
    if(i%4 == 0 && i > 0)
    {
        printf("\n------------------------\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the problem in your output code: your `printf`s use `userBoard.user[location]` for all 16 cells (i.e. you are printing the same characters 16 times).

This kind of error is what one usually gets for 'copy&paste programming'. Use loops.

And I suppose you should print 12 cells, not 16.